# How to do a redirect in Liferay/Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, liferay, redirect, liferay-6, tomcat6

Later Edit: we didn't really want to, but ultimately had to resort to do a redirect from the start page i.e. modifying the header to always redirect when the start page is loaded.

I need to make a redirect from a Liferay 6 that runs on a tomcat 6 to another website. The old page running on the Liferay 6 is going to be faded out, but we still need it for the old URL.
How can I make it so that when the old URL is called it redirects to the new one.

Following answers are not viable:

1. updating the tomcat and/or liferay
2. putting an apache webserver and/or nginx in front of it
3. modyfing the actual start page

I do understand that the tech is old and the question might not even have a 'good' answer. I am also pretty sure, the fastest way would be #3.
I am asking this question to see if there are other ways to do it.

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Can you inject a little js in the liferay page using theme settings?

Comment: "fade out but needed for the old URL", what does that mean? Do you still need the old content to stay available, or just anything that doesn't result in 404 errors? Currently I read that you want to change everything without changing anything, or you're just arbitrarily are adding constraints

Comment: Please list out your requirements clearly on the logging,analytics,any predefined actions on redirection and then decide up on an approach.